# Convert bytes to a string in Python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I captured the standard output of an external program into a `bytes` object:

```
>>> from subprocess import *
>>> stdout = Popen(['ls', '-l'], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
>>> stdout
b'total 0\n-rw-rw-r-- 1 thomas thomas 0 Mar  3 07:03 file1\n-rw-rw-r-- 1 thomas thomas 0 Mar  3 07:03 file2\n'
```

I want to convert that to a normal Python string, so that I can print it like this:

```
>>> print(stdout)
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thomas thomas 0 Mar  3 07:03 file1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thomas thomas 0 Mar  3 07:03 file2
```

How do I convert the `bytes` object to a `str` with Python 3?

---

<sub>See [Best way to convert string to bytes in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435) for the other way around.</sub>

Comment: why doesn't `str(text_bytes)` work? This seems bizarre to me.

Comment: @CharlieParker Because `str(text_bytes)` can't specify the encoding. Depending on what's in text_bytes, `text_bytes.decode('cp1250`)` might result in a very different string to `text_bytes.decode('utf-8')`.

Comment: so `str` function does not convert to a real string anymore. One HAS to say an encoding explicitly for some reason I am to lazy to read through why. Just convert it to `utf-8` and see if ur code works. e.g. `var = var.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: @CraigAnderson: `unicode_text = str(bytestring, character_encoding)` works as expected on Python 3. Though `unicode_text = bytestring.decode(character_encoding)` is more preferable to avoid confusion with just `str(bytes_obj)` that produces a text representation for `bytes_obj` instead of decoding it to text: `str(b'\xb6', 'cp1252') == b'\xb6'.decode('cp1252') == '¶'` and `str(b'\xb6') == "b'\\xb6'" == repr(b'\xb6') != '¶'`

Comment: Also, you can pass `text=True` to `subprocess.run()` or `.Popen()` and then you'll get a string back, no need to convert bytes. Or specify `encoding="utf-8"` to either function.

Comment: @CharlieParker - I don't think I've ever come across a use-case for the string that you get when you `str(<bytes>)`, but maybe it's just for consistency with other `str` calls. I would have thought they could default to UTF-8 encoding, but maybe it's because Windows has too many funny encodings that it doesn't default to UTF-8; but I agree with you.

Answer (score 5691, accepted):

[Decode the `bytes` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) to produce a string:

```
>>> b"abcde".decode("utf-8")
'abcde'
```

The above example *assumes* that the `bytes` object is in UTF-8, because it is a common encoding. However, you should use the encoding your data is actually in!

Comment: Yes, but given that this is the output from a windows command, shouldn't it instead be using ".decode('windows-1252')" ?

Comment: Using `"windows-1252"` is not reliable either (e.g., for other language versions of Windows), wouldn't it be best to use `sys.stdout.encoding`?

Comment: Maybe this will help somebody further: Sometimes you use byte array for e.x. TCP communication. If you want to convert byte array to string cutting off trailing '\x00' characters the following answer is not enough. Use b'example\x00\x00'.decode('utf-8').strip('\x00') then.

Comment: **Official documentation for this:** for all `bytes` and `bytearray` operations (methods which can be called on these objects), see here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-methods. For `bytes.decode()` in particular, see here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode.

Comment: just decode() cause utf-8 is default

Answer (score 418):

Decode the byte string and turn it in to a character (Unicode) string.

---

Python 3:

```
encoding = 'utf-8'
b'hello'.decode(encoding)
```

or

```
str(b'hello', encoding)
```

---

Python 2:

```
encoding = 'utf-8'
'hello'.decode(encoding)
```

or

```
unicode('hello', encoding)
```

Comment: just decode() cause utf-8 is default

Answer (score 263):

This joins together a list of bytes into a string:

```
>>> bytes_data = [112, 52, 52]
>>> "".join(map(chr, bytes_data))
'p44'
```

Comment: @leetNightshade: yet it is terribly inefficient. If you have a byte array you only need to decode.

Comment: @Sasszem: this method is a perverted way to express: `a.decode('latin-1')` where `a = bytearray([112, 52, 52])` (["There Ain't No Such Thing as Plain Text"](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). If you've managed to convert bytes into a text string then you used some encoding—`latin-1` in this case)

Comment: @leetNightshade: For completeness sake: `bytes(list_of_integers).decode('ascii')` is about 1/3rd faster than `''.join(map(chr, list_of_integers))` on Python 3.6.

Answer (score 131):

[In Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode), the default encoding is `"utf-8"`, so you can directly use:

```
b'hello'.decode()
```

which is equivalent to

```
b'hello'.decode(encoding="utf-8")
```

On the other hand, [in Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode), encoding defaults to the default string encoding. Thus, you should use:

```
b'hello'.decode(encoding)
```

where `encoding` is the encoding you want.

[**Note:**](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode) support for keyword arguments was added in Python 2.7.

Comment: Great to point out decode() w/ utf-8 is default

Answer (score 130):

If you don't know the encoding, then to read binary input into string in Python 3 and Python 2 compatible way, use the ancient MS-DOS [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) encoding:

```
PY3K = sys.version_info >= (3, 0)

lines = []
for line in stream:
    if not PY3K:
        lines.append(line)
    else:
        lines.append(line.decode('cp437'))
```

Because encoding is unknown, expect non-English symbols to translate to characters of `cp437` (English characters are not translated, because they match in most single byte encodings and UTF-8).

Decoding arbitrary binary input to UTF-8 is unsafe, because you may get this:

```
>>> b'\x00\x01\xffsd'.decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 2: invalid
start byte
```

The same applies to `latin-1`, which was popular (the default?) for Python 2. See the missing points in [Codepage Layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout) - it is where Python chokes with infamous `ordinal not in range`.

**UPDATE 20150604**: There are rumors that Python 3 has the `surrogateescape` error strategy for encoding stuff into binary data without data loss and crashes, but it needs conversion tests, `[binary] -> [str] -> [binary]`, to validate both performance and reliability.

**UPDATE 20170116**: Thanks to comment by Nearoo - there is also a possibility to slash escape all unknown bytes with `backslashreplace` error handler. That works only for Python 3, so even with this workaround you will still get inconsistent output from different Python versions:

```
PY3K = sys.version_info >= (3, 0)

lines = []
for line in stream:
    if not PY3K:
        lines.append(line)
    else:
        lines.append(line.decode('utf-8', 'backslashreplace'))
```

See *[Python’s Unicode Support](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#python-s-unicode-support)* for details.

**UPDATE 20170119**: I decided to implement slash escaping decode that works for both Python 2 and Python 3. It should be slower than the `cp437` solution, but it should produce **identical results** on every Python version.

```
# --- preparation

import codecs

def slashescape(err):
    """ codecs error handler. err is UnicodeDecode instance. return
    a tuple with a replacement for the unencodable part of the input
    and a position where encoding should continue"""
    #print err, dir(err), err.start, err.end, err.object[:err.start]
    thebyte = err.object[err.start:err.end]
    repl = u'\\x'+hex(ord(thebyte))[2:]
    return (repl, err.end)

codecs.register_error('slashescape', slashescape)

# --- processing

stream = [b'\x80abc']

lines = []
for line in stream:
    lines.append(line.decode('utf-8', 'slashescape'))
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The latin-1, i.e. ISO-8859-1 encoding is perfectly capable of handling arbitrary binary data - `bytes(range(256)).decode('latin-1')` runs without error on modern Python versions, and I can't come up with a reason why it ever would have failed. The *entire point* of Latin-1 is that it maps each byte to the first 256 code points in Unicode - or rather, the ordering of Unicode was chosen, ever since the first version in 1991, so that the first 256 code points would match Latin-1. You could run into problems **printing** the string, but that's entirely orthogonal.

Answer (score 48):

I think you actually want this:

```
>>> from subprocess import *
>>> command_stdout = Popen(['ls', '-l'], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
>>> command_text = command_stdout.decode(encoding='windows-1252')
```

Aaron's answer was correct, except that you need to know *which* encoding to use. And I believe that Windows uses 'windows-1252'. It will only matter if you have some unusual (non-ASCII) characters in your content, but then it will make a difference.

By the way, the fact that it *does* matter is the reason that Python moved to using two different types for binary and text data: it can't convert magically between them, because it doesn't know the encoding unless you tell it! The only way YOU would know is to read the Windows documentation (or read it here).

Answer (score 48):

Since this question is actually asking about `subprocess` output, you have more direct approaches available. The most modern would be using [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) and passing `text=True` (Python 3.7+) to automatically decode stdout using the system default coding:

```
text = subprocess.check_output(["ls", "-l"], text=True)
```

For Python 3.6, `Popen` accepts an [*encoding*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) keyword:

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> text = Popen(['ls', '-l'], stdout=PIPE, encoding='utf-8').communicate()[0]
>>> type(text)
str
>>> print(text)
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 wim badger 0 May 31 12:45 some_file.txt
```

The general answer to the question in the title, if you're not dealing with subprocess output, is to *decode* bytes to text:

```
>>> b'abcde'.decode()
'abcde'
```

With no argument, [`sys.getdefaultencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getdefaultencoding) will be used.  If your data is not `sys.getdefaultencoding()`, then you must specify the encoding explicitly in the [`decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) call:

```
>>> b'caf\xe9'.decode('cp1250')
'café'
```

Answer (score 38):

Set universal_newlines to True, i.e.

```
command_stdout = Popen(['ls', '-l'], stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True).communicate()[0]
```

Comment: [On 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#subprocess) you can (and should) do `text=True` instead of `universal_newlines=True`.

Answer (score 38):

To interpret a byte sequence as a text, you have to know the
corresponding character encoding:

```
unicode_text = bytestring.decode(character_encoding)
```

Example:

```
>>> b'\xc2\xb5'.decode('utf-8')
'µ'
```

`ls` command may produce output that can't be interpreted as text. File names
on Unix may be any sequence of bytes except slash `b'/'` and zero
`b'\0'`:

```
>>> open(bytes(range(0x100)).translate(None, b'\0/'), 'w').close()
```

Trying to decode such byte soup using utf-8 encoding raises `UnicodeDecodeError`.

It can be worse. The decoding may fail silently and produce [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)
if you use a wrong incompatible encoding:

```
>>> '—'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252')
'â€”'
```

The data is corrupted but your program remains unaware that a failure
has occurred.

In general, what character encoding to use is not embedded in the byte sequence itself. You have to communicate this info out-of-band. Some outcomes are more likely than others and therefore `chardet` module exists that can *guess* the character encoding. A single Python script may use multiple character encodings in different places.

---

`ls` output can be converted to a Python string using `os.fsdecode()`
function that succeeds even for [undecodable
filenames](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0383/) (it uses
`sys.getfilesystemencoding()` and `surrogateescape` error handler on
Unix):

```
import os
import subprocess

output = os.fsdecode(subprocess.check_output('ls'))
```

To get the original bytes, you could use `os.fsencode()`.

If you pass `universal_newlines=True` parameter then `subprocess` uses
`locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` to decode bytes e.g., it can be
`cp1252` on Windows.

To decode the byte stream on-the-fly,
[`io.TextIOWrapper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper)
could be used: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25945031/4279).

Different commands may use different character encodings for their
output e.g., `dir` internal command (`cmd`) may use cp437. To decode its
output, you could pass the encoding explicitly (Python 3.6+):

```
output = subprocess.check_output('dir', shell=True, encoding='cp437')
```

The filenames may differ from `os.listdir()` (which uses Windows
Unicode API) e.g., `'\xb6'` can be substituted with `'\x14'`—Python's
cp437 codec maps `b'\x14'` to control character U+0014 instead of
U+00B6 (¶). To support filenames with arbitrary Unicode characters, see  [Decode PowerShell output possibly containing non-ASCII Unicode characters into a Python string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33936074/4279)

Answer (score 28):

While [@Aaron Maenpaa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33688948/1587329) just works, a user [recently asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688837/urllib-for-python-3/33688948#comment55151210_33688948):

> Is there any more simply way? 'fhand.read().decode("ASCII")' [...] It's so long!

You can use:

```
command_stdout.decode()
```

`decode()` has a [standard argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-and-bytearray-operations):

> `codecs.decode(obj, encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')`

Answer (score 21):

If you have had this error:

> utf-8 codec can't decode byte 0x8a,

then it is better to use the following code to convert bytes to a string:

```py
bytes = b"abcdefg"
string = bytes.decode("utf-8", "ignore")
```

Answer (score 20):

If you should get the following by trying `decode()`:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

You can also specify the encoding type straight in a cast:

```
>>> my_byte_str
b'Hello World'

>>> str(my_byte_str, 'utf-8')
'Hello World'
```

Answer (score 20):

### Bytes

```
m=b'This is bytes'
```

### ***Converting to string***

### Method 1

```
m.decode("utf-8")
```

or

```
m.decode()
```

### Method 2

```
import codecs
codecs.decode(m,encoding="utf-8")
```

or

```
import codecs
codecs.decode(m)
```

### Method 3

```
str(m,encoding="utf-8")
```

or

```
str(m)[2:-1]
```

### Result

```
'This is bytes'
```

Answer (score 17):

We can decode the bytes object to produce a string using `bytes.decode(encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')`.
For documentation see *[bytes.decode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode)*.

Python 3 example:

```
byte_value = b"abcde"
print("Initial value = {}".format(byte_value))
print("Initial value type = {}".format(type(byte_value)))
string_value = byte_value.decode("utf-8")
# utf-8 is used here because it is a very common encoding, but you need to use the encoding your data is actually in.
print("------------")
print("Converted value = {}".format(string_value))
print("Converted value type = {}".format(type(string_value)))
```

Output:

```
Initial value = b'abcde'
Initial value type = <class 'bytes'>
------------
Converted value = abcde
Converted value type = <class 'str'>
```

Note: In Python 3, by default the encoding type is UTF-8. So, `<byte_string>.decode("utf-8")` can be also written as `<byte_string>.decode()`

Answer (score 8):

For Python 3, this is a much safer and *Pythonic* approach to convert from `byte` to `string`:

```
def byte_to_str(bytes_or_str):
    if isinstance(bytes_or_str, bytes): # Check if it's in bytes
        print(bytes_or_str.decode('utf-8'))
    else:
        print("Object not of byte type")

byte_to_str(b'total 0\n-rw-rw-r-- 1 thomas thomas 0 Mar  3 07:03 file1\n-rw-rw-r-- 1 thomas thomas 0 Mar  3 07:03 file2\n')
```

Output:

```
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thomas thomas 0 Mar  3 07:03 file1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thomas thomas 0 Mar  3 07:03 file2
```

Answer (score 7):

When working with data from Windows systems (with `\r\n` line endings), my answer is

```
String = Bytes.decode("utf-8").replace("\r\n", "\n")
```

Why? Try this with a multiline Input.txt:

```
Bytes = open("Input.txt", "rb").read()
String = Bytes.decode("utf-8")
open("Output.txt", "w").write(String)
```

All your line endings will be doubled (to `\r\r\n`), leading to extra empty lines. Python's text-read functions usually normalize line endings so that strings use only `\n`. If you receive binary data from a Windows system, Python does not have a chance to do that. Thus,

```
Bytes = open("Input.txt", "rb").read()
String = Bytes.decode("utf-8").replace("\r\n", "\n")
open("Output.txt", "w").write(String)
```

will replicate your original file.

Answer (score 5):

For your *specific* case of "run a shell command and get its output as text instead of bytes", on Python 3.7, you should use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) and pass in `text=True` (as well as `capture_output=True` to capture the output)

```
command_result = subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"], capture_output=True, text=True)
command_result.stdout  # is a `str` containing your program's stdout
```

`text` used to be called `universal_newlines`, and was changed (well, aliased) in Python 3.7. If you want to support Python versions before 3.7, pass in `universal_newlines=True` instead of `text=True`

Answer (score 3):

From *[sys — System-specific parameters and functions](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html)*:

To write or read binary data from/to the standard streams, use the underlying binary buffer. For example, to write bytes to stdout, use `sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'abc')`.

Comment: The pipe to the subprocess is *already* a binary buffer. Your answer fails to address how to get a string value from the resulting `bytes` value.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
bytes.fromhex('c3a9').decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the best ways to convert to string without caring about any encoding type is as follows -

```py
import json


b_string = b'test string'
string = b_string.decode(
    json.detect_encoding(b_string)  # detect_encoding - used to detect encoding
)
print(string)
```

Here, we used `json.detect_encoding` method to detect the encoding.

Answer (score 1):

```
def toString(string):    
    try:
        return v.decode("utf-8")
    except ValueError:
        return string

b = b'97.080.500'
s = '97.080.500'
print(toString(b))
print(toString(s))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit] your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Comment: Hi @Dev-iL, if you are a moderator, can you tell me if it's possible for moderators to delete pointless empty incoherent answers like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68310461/134044

Comment: @NeilG I'm not a moderator (note that I have no diamond next to my nickname). If you think a post is low quality, you should report it, and if the community agrees with you - it will be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert any bytes, not just string converted to bytes:

```
with open("bytesfile", "rb") as infile:
    str = base64.b85encode(imageFile.read())

with open("bytesfile", "rb") as infile:
    str2 = json.dumps(list(infile.read()))
```

This is not very efficient, however. It will turn a 2 MB picture into 9 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this one; this function will ignore all the non-character sets (like UTF-8) binaries and return a clean string. It is tested for Python 3.6 and above.

```py
def bin2str(text, encoding = 'utf-8'):
    """Converts a binary to Unicode string by removing all non Unicode char
    text: binary string to work on
    encoding: output encoding *utf-8"""

    return text.decode(encoding, 'ignore')
```

Here, the function will take the binary and decode it (converts binary data to characters using the Python predefined character set and the `ignore` argument ignores all non-character set data from your binary and finally returns your desired `string` value.

If you are not sure about the encoding, use `sys.getdefaultencoding()` to get the default encoding of your device.